# different queries for the same table in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, data-modeling

In my Cassandra query-based model, I design a table with the following primary keys: `((timestamp, fraction_in_time), sensor_id, big_sensor_id)`

As you guess the `timestamp` and `fraction_in_time` are partition key and `sensor_id` and `big_sensor_id` are clustering key.

The Domain is storing data from sensors and we have two sensors, a big sensor including several small sensors.

The primary key is design for this main query: **Get all(or subset specified using id) sensors data for the given period of time**.

On the other hand, I want to pass another query: **Get all(or subset specified using time) data for a given sensor id**.

I have created a materialized view for the second question using primary key: `((sensor_id, big_sensor_id), timestamp, fraction_in_time)`, but it duplicates all data and need so much more storage! Is there any other standard way to handle this situation?

Comment: can you please describe the table? I mean data types and the approximate amount of data.

Comment: denormalization and duplication is a common practice in cassandra as well as one column family for one query

Comment: @RJMIMI38 consider 30 column including just primary data type, like long, varchar and int